# Bootstrap Modal - display live camera

Tags: javascript, html, camera, modal-dialog, popup

I want to display camera in the pop-up window. I have structure to start the modal window and to start camera but do not know how to send the live camera view to the bootstrap window. All the examples I saw were with displaying external sources like youtube or locally stored files - but did not find the example how to display camera.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 </head>

  <body>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
<br>
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#livestream_scanner">scan
                    <i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>
                </button>
    </span>
        </div>  <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>  <!-- /.row -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
    #interactive.viewport {position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;}
    #interactive.viewport > canvas, #interactive.viewport > video {max-width: 100%; width: 100%;}
    canvas.drawing, canvas.drawingBuffer {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

// Start the live stream when the modal opens
    $('#livestream_scanner').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

// how to send camera to the pop-up window?
// the code just belowe starts camera but is not displaying it in the pop-up window

 var video = document.querySelector("#viewport.interactive");
 if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
 }


    });
});

</script>

<div class="modal" id="livestream_scanner">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Barcode Scanner</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="position: static">
                <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <label class="btn btn-default pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Use camera app
                    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="camera" class="hidden" />
                </label>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you have your selector the wrong way around. the id is `interactive` and the class is `viewport` but your selector is `#viewport.interactive`.

Comment: thanks for reply - the other way  with #interactive.viewport is not working either - probably I am missing something not defined yet - to make the camera stream properly assigned and displayed in the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

it appeared that the the video definition was missing in the interactive viewport:

```
<div id="interactive" class="viewport">
<video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
</div>
```

and in the script to be used:

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
```